# JavaScript heap out of memory - error while inserting into mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I want to insert 1500000 documents in MongoDB. First, I query a database and get a list of 15000 instructors from there and for each instructor I want to insert 100 courses by each of them.

I run two loops: first it loops through all instructors and secondly, in each iteration it will insert 100 docs for that id as in the code below:

```
const instructors = await Instructor.find();
//const insrtuctor contains 15000 instructor
instructors.forEach((insructor) => {
    for(let i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        const course = new Course({
            title: faker.lorem.sentence(),
            description: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
            author: insructor._id,
            prise: Math.floor(Math.random()*11),
            isPublished: 'true',
            tags: ["java", "Nodejs", "javascript"]
        });
        course.save().then(result => {
            console.log(result._id);
            Instructor.findByIdAndUpdate(insructor._id, { $push: { courses: course._id } })
            .then(insructor => {
                console.log(`Instructor Id : ${insructor._id} add Course : ${i} `);
            }).catch(err => next(err));
            console.log(`Instructor id: ${ insructor._id } add Course: ${i}`)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
});
```

Here is my `package.json` file where I put something I found on the internet:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon app.js",
        "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "faker": "^4.1.0",
        "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.6",
    }
}
```

This is my course model definition

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Course = mongoose.model('courses', new mongoose.Schema({

title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3
},
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'instructor'
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
},
ratings: [{
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    }
}],
tags: [String],
rating: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    default: 0
},
ratedBy: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    default: 0
},
prise: {
    type: Number,
    required: function() { this.isPublished },
    min: 0
},
isPublished: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
}
}));

module.exports = Course;
```

Comment: Your code has unbalanced braces and parentheses.

Comment: @trincot it's part of code so may have unbalanced braces but it's not throwing error there

Comment: Sure, but we cannot see your "here", so please do the effort to at least make your question's code consistent.

Comment: @trincot okay I'll be careful next time

Comment: You can click "edit" and make corrections.

Comment: Never mind, I updated it for you ;-)

Comment: @Shekhar You're doing wrong. Big amount of data need to be processed "**on the wire**". Idea is that if You get one item - You process that one item in place. Which is possible with cursors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **big** amount of **data** You've to **use cursors**.

**Idea** is to **process** document **asap** as You get **one** from db.

Like You're **asking db to give instructors** and **db sends** back **with small batches** and You operate with that batch and process them **until reach** the **end** of all batches.

**Otherwise** `await Instructor.find()` will **load** all **data** **to memory** and **populate** that **instances** with mongoose methods that You don't need.

Even `await Instructor.find().lean()` will not give memory benefit.

Cursor is **mongodb's feature** when You do `find` on collection.

With mongoose it's accessible using: `Instructor.collection.find({})`

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdI1VDaTlhk).

Below I've written solution for batch processing data using cursor.

Add this somewhere inside the module:

```
const createCourseForInstructor = (instructor) => {
  const data = {
    title: faker.lorem.sentence(),
    description: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
    author: instructor._id,
    prise: Math.floor(Math.random()*11), // typo: "prise", must be: "price"
    isPublished: 'true',
    tags: ["java", "Nodejs", "javascript"]
  };
  return Course.create(data);
}

const assignCourseToInstructor = (course, instructor) => {
  const where = {_id: instructor._id};
  const operation = {$push: {courses: course._id}};
  return Instructor.collection.updateOne(where, operation, {upsert: false});
}

const processInstructor = async (instructor) => {
  let courseIds = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    try {
      const course = await createCourseForInstructor(instructor)
      await assignCourseToInstructor(course, instructor);
      courseIds.push(course._id);
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }
  console.log(
    'Created ', courseIds.length, 'courses for', 
    'Instructor:', instructor._id, 
    'Course ids:', courseIds
  );
};
```

and in Your asynchronous block replace Your loop with:

```
const cursor = await Instructor.collection.find({}).batchSize(1000);

while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
  const instructor = await cursor.next();
  await processInstructor(instructor);
}
```

P.S. I'm using native `collection.find` and `collection.updateOne` for **performance** to **avoid** mongoose use **extra heap** for mongoose methods and fields **on model instances**.

**BONUS:**

Even **if** **with** this **cursor** solution Your code will **get out of memory** issue **again**, **run** Your **code** like in this example (define size in megabytes according server's ram):

```
nodemon --expose-gc --max_old_space_size=10240 app.js
```

Comment: Getting this kind of error : E11000 duplicate key error collection: Courser.courses index: ratings.user_1 dup key: { : null } when executing i have added my course model definition in question

Comment: @Shekhar issue with unique key is different question. But I'll answer with fix: 1. remove this: `unique: true` from Course model definition, 2. go to database using robomongo or studio3t and remove unique index from that field in collection, 3. create CourseRating schema and model and keep ratings there since it's different entity

Comment: This is working super fast thank you so much really appreciate your time

Comment: @Shekhar my pleasure. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are not awaiting the promises returned by `save`, and immediately continue with the next iterations of the `for` and `forEach` loops. This means you are launching a huge amount of (pending) `save` operations, which will indeed grow the memory usage by the mongodb library.

It would be better to wait for a `save` (and  the chained `findByIdAndUpdate`) to resolve before continuing with the next iterations.

Since you are apparently in an `async` function context, you can use `await` for this, provided that you replace the `forEach` loop with a `for` loop (so that you remain in the same function context):

```
async function yourFunction() {
    const instructors = await Instructor.find();
    for (let instructor of instructors) { // Use `for` loop to allow for more `await`
        for (let i=0; i<10; i++) { // You want 10 times, right?
            const course = new Course({
                title: faker.lorem.sentence(),
                description: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
                author: instructor._id,
                prise: Math.floor(Math.random()*11),
                isPublished: 'true',
                tags: ["java", "Nodejs", "javascript"]
            });
            const result = await course.save();
            console.log(result._id);
            instructor = await Instructor.findByIdAndUpdate(instructor._id, { $push: { courses: course._id } });
            console.log(`Instructor Id : ${instructor._id} add Course : ${i}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all the `save` operations are serialised: the next only starts when the previous has completed.

Note that I have not included the error handling you had: this should best be done with a `catch` call chained to the call of this `async` function.

Comment: By doing: `const instructors = await Instructor.find();` mongoose will load all instructors to memory + mongoose will populate every item (instance) of array with mongoose methods - that will make huge memory waste, even with `Instructor.find().lean()` it will not be effective.

Comment: now program execute but i get this error   E11000 duplicate key error collection: Courser.courses index: ratings.user_1 dup key: { : null }

Comment: @Shekhar, that sounds like a different question. Your code does not include anything that populates `ratings`. I would suggest that you ask a new question, focussing on that problem.

Comment: Yes, I saw. Please ask a new question. You should not use one question to ask follow-up questions.